Django/Python - How to assign a file path variable in a platform-independent way?
I have a Django project where one of the .env file variables is going to represent an absolute file path.  E.g.,
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY='blah_blah_blah'
MY_STORAGE_PATH = 'D:\\files\\for\\my\\project'

Obviously the above would work fine on a Windows machine with a D: drive, but it's no good if there's no D: drive or if the machine is using some other OS.
Now I can think of any number of functioning ways to supply this .env string in a platform-independent way, and then use string manipulation and the os.path methods to assemble the actual path.  I could break out the drive & path separately, using a 'neutral' path separator of my own choosing:
MY_STORAGE_DRIVE_FOR_WIN = 'D:'
MY_STORAGE_PATH  = '|files|for|my|project'

...I could supply the configuration formatted as a list, convert it to a real list, then feed into os.path.join():
MY_STORAGE_PATH_ELEMENTS  = '["files","for","my","project"]'

...and so on, and so on.
But before I go roll my own that way, I wanted to know:  is there some accepted convention for this kind of use case?  (Surely this isn't the first time someone needed to provide an .env value to represent a platform-independent path?)

I'm not sure what are you trying to do. If you provide it for something cross-platform yourself, you must somehow account for windows vs unix paths (note that you don't need to care about separator, just use forward slash always) - you can't have drive on unix and can't omit the drive on windows. I also hardly understand the reasoning: drive issues aside, it's a good habit to follow platform conventions (so ~/.local or ~/.config or ~/.cache entry, depending on the nature of files) - I'd recommend to just ask the user for this .env entry and avoid configuring/defaulting it globally.

If it's something temporary, consider tempfile first, of course, which is cross-platform, and otherwise please give more details about your use case (XY). If that's for Django file storage, definitely consider configuring it per-deployment, that will save a lot of trouble later trying to migrate to cloud, or just adding a few more storage drives. Also slashes

Why are you even worrying about this when the purpose of a .env file / environment variables is so that configuration can easily be different for different machines  / environments? A person who has a D drive can write a path like that, one who doesn't can put up some other  path or someone who uses Linux can set up the path with forward slashes.

@AbdulAzizBarkat -- Yes, thanks -- I wondered whether I was just overthinking the problem.  So basically, there's nothing "bad" in just having the single string, and expecting it would be populated according to the local OS & available drives?  If that's the case I'm content to do that.  (Keeping It Simple.)

@JDM yeah, if the same value is supposed to work for everyone it wouldn't even make sense to have it as an environment variable, it might as well be directly hardcoded in your code.

I would use a separator that's not going to be part of a sane filepath on any platform. Maybe '//'. Given ENVVAR = "D://first//second//file.name":
pathname = os.path.join( *ENVVAR.split('//'))

os.path.join will insert whatever separator is needed on the platform on which it is run.
If you want to code defensively you also output a warning  if there are any "suspicious" single slashes or backslashes in ENVVAR.
